# How much time typically a load testing takes for any application to give the metrics?

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing

How much time it takes to receive metrics like throughput, response time , latency etc after performing a performance or load test?

Are there any references for it and theories behind it? Also are there links on performing a manual load testing on a web application which we have developed?

Answer (score 0):

All the [performance metrics](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420665-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites) are normally available immediately after 1st request has been executed, the more requests you collect the more accurate the measurement is.

There is no rocket science behind it, for each request performance testing tool records:

- request start time
- request end time
- protocol based metrics (connect time, latency)
- success or failure
- request and response size

when there is more than one request some more metrics are calculated:

- [average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) response time
- response time [percentiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile)
- throughput (number of requests per unit of time)

See i.e. [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) for the metrics explained.

---

With regards to "manual load testing on a web application" you can only perform a [client-side performance testing](http://manual%20load%20testing%20on%20a%20web%20application), i.e. check resources download, rendering speed, JavaScript performance, etc.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri! Can you also point out some popular books on theoretical concepts of performance or load testing?